# Node.js Module Function Callback

Tags: node.js, electron

Hello I am trying to create a Node.js function to return a value from sqlite query but the function always return **undefined**.

**Module Function:**

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('dbex.db');
const fs = require('fs')
 module.exports = {  
  initDB: () => {
    let queryInit = fs.readFileSync('db.sql', 'utf8');
    db.exec(queryInit);
  },
  sqlite_insert: async (Sqlite_Query) => {
    db.exec(queryInit);
  },
  sqlite_query: async (Sqlite_Query,callback = () => {}) => {
    db.all(Sqlite_Query, function(err,rows){
      if(err) return callback(err);
      //db.close();
      return callback(null,rows);
      }); 
  },
  getSetting: async (setting) => { 
  await db.get('SELECT * FROM `app_setting` where setting_name="'+setting+'"', function (error, results) {
       console.log(results);
    if(error) {
      return error;  
    }    
    return results.setting_value;   
    });  
   }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var SQL = require('../services/db/sqlite.js');

document.querySelector('#btnSyncData').addEventListener('click', () => {
  
var test = SQL.getSetting('user_branch');
 
console.log(test);
 
})
```

Any Advice to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `async/await` and also keep returning both error(if any) or success.
Like below. Your exports might be like the following:

```
module.exports = {  
  getSetting: async (setting) => { 
  await db.all(`SELECT * FROM `app_setting` where 
  setting_name="'+setting+'"',      
   function (error, results) {
    if(error) {
      return error;  
    }    
    return results[0].setting_value;   
    });  
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the Post question Codes with your instruction, and now I get the following in Console Log:  Promise {<pending>} , I there are something wrong from my side?

Comment: Yes, just `console.log(result)` and see what you are getting. Then you have to return the desired keys. Also focus on single and double quotes used in the select query. Also see is `db.all()...` is accessible inside the getSetting() module.

Comment: Thank you, console.log(result) return results successfully, but when I am call the function I got Promise {<pending>} , I think there are something wrong when I am call the function.

Comment: yes call the function using async/await as well

Comment: Thank you, But Unfortunately I don't know haw to call it using async/await, but thanks for you help.

Comment: To call the function, just do the following.
const setting = 'whatever_you_pass';
const getResult = async (setting) => {
 const result = await getSetting(setting);
console.log(result);
return result;
}

Comment: Thank you, I updated the call to : 
var SQL = require('../services/db/sqlite.js');
const setting = 'user_branch'; 
const getResult = async (setting) => { 
  const result = await SQL.getSetting(setting); 
  return result; 
}  , 


The prevoius message gone, But the console shows the code not the result

(setting) => { 
  const result = SQL.getSetting(setting); 
  return result; 
}

Comment: I think you have to include the object like: `const { getSetting } = require("../services/db/sqlite.js");` and try again. Then you have to call like: `const result = await getSetting(setting);` and console the result to see what you get back.